# Automation Script failing for different API level 22

Tags: java, android, api, automation, appium

I'm writing my Automation script for an android apk using Appium in Java language. My automation script runs fine for emulator with API Level 19 and fails for devices/emulator with API level 22. Not sure if it might fail for other APIs. Exception I get in the script is that the AndroidDriver instance is always null, i.e. saying that the driver is null